# Space-efficient pickling of Cython objects in Python?

Tags: python, struct, cython, pickle, namedtuple

I'm trying to find a space-efficient way to store a struct-like object in Python.

```
# file point.py

import collections
Point = collections.namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
```

Here's the cythonized version:

```
# file cpoint.pyx

cdef class CPoint:

    cdef readonly int x
    cdef readonly int y

    def __init__(self, int x, int y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Point(x={}, y={})'.format(self.x, self.y)
```

I expect the cythonized version to be more memory-efficient:

```
from pympler.asizeof import asizeof
from point import Point
from cpoint import CPoint

asizeof(Point(1,2))     # returns 184
asizeof(CPoint(1,2))    # returns 24
```

But surprisingly the cythonized version takes up more space when pickled  despite static typing and a lighter in-memory representation.

```
import pickle
len(pickle.dumps(Point(1,2)))     # returns 28
len(pickle.dumps(CPoint(1,2)))    # returns 70
```

Is there a more efficient way to serialize cython objects like this?

---

#### Follow-up

The reason I'd like to preserve the individual `CPoint` objects is because I'm receiving heterogenous `CPoint`-like objects in a streaming application, so I need to buffer them in a `list` of heterogenous types.

It is indeed possible to improve the storage footprint using numpy arrays if we had guarantees on the types of elements of the list. It's also likely that we'll get better compression properties with a homogenous container, but you'll have to give up the versatility of serializing unstructured data.

One algorithmic solution to fall back on the spatial advantage of homogenous containers proposed by @ead and @DavidW while accommodating unstructured data would be to store a bitmap of the positions of the objects in front (assuming we know all the possible types of incoming objects at bytecode compilation time, which is a broad assumption), then still group the objects in homogenous containers. And maybe it's possible to extract further efficiency by ordering them in a column-oriented fashion so that the compression picks it up better. It's hard to say without benchmarking.

Comment: The "real" question with heterogeneous lists is quite different from the original question, so it might be worth posting as a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't specifically a Cython solution, but: presumably if you're worried about the size on disk then you have lots of these. In which case a good option is to store the data in a [numpy structured array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.rec.html) to avoid creating lots of Python objects (or possibly something like Pandas instead).

I'd also expect pickling an array/numpy list of objects to be a more useful representation of size than pickling an individual one (I believe `pickle` does some optimizations for when you have a lot of the same thing)

```
import collections
from cpoint import CPoint

Point = collections.namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])

l = [ Point(n,n) for n in range(10000) ]
l2 = [ CPoint(n,n) for n in range(10000) ]

import numpy as np
l3 = np.array(list(zip(list(range(10000)), list(range(10000)))),
              dtype=[('x',int),('y',int)])

import pickle
print("Point",len(pickle.dumps(l))/20000)
print("CPoint",len(pickle.dumps(l2))/20000)
print("nparray",len(pickle.dumps(l3))/20000)
```

This prints:

> Point 9.9384
>
> CPoint 16.4402
>
> nparray 8.01215

The `namedtuple` and `numpy.array` versions are both pretty close to the 8-bytes per int limit that we expect, but the numpy array version is better.

---

Interestingly, if we add `protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL` to the call then everything improves further and the `namedtuple` version wins convincingly again. (I suspect it's noticed that it doesn't need full 64bit ints to store, and I doubt if this will be easy to beat manually)

> Point 5.9775
>
> CPoint 10.47975
>
> nparray 8.0107

Comment: This experiment is a little bit biased in my opinion: in OP’s case Cython-int is 4 byte, so `np.int32` and not `int` should be used for the numpy structured array. Also bigger numbers should be used for the Point-coordinates, otherwise `np.int16` could do the job.

Answer (score 1):

On the one hand this answer should be an addition to the answer of @DavidW but on the other hand it also investigates possible improvements. It also proposes to use a wrapper for serialization, which would keep the beloved CPoint-objects but achieves the same dense serialization as structured numpy-arrays.

As already pointed out, it doesn't make much sense to compare sizes of the single serialized object - the is just too much overhead. Among other things, Python has to save the identifier of the class, which is the full name of the module+class name. In my case, I'm using ipython with %%cython-magic, it is pretty long:

```
>>> print(pickle.dumps(CPoint(1,2)))
b'\x80\x03c_cython_magic_46e1a18d1df9b5ea5ee974991f9aba67\n__pyx_unpickle_CPoint\nq\x00c_cython_magic_46e1a18d1df9b5ea5ee974991f9aba67\nCPoint\nq\x01J\xe9\x1a\x8d\x0cK\x01K\x02\x86q\x02\x87q\x03Rq\x04.'
```

The length of the automatically created name of the module is `c_cython_magic_46e1a18d1df9b5ea5ee974991f9aba67` and that hurts!

So basically, without knowing how your objects are stored (list, map, set or something else), there is no way to give a proper answer.

However, similar to @DavidW, a will assume that the points are stored in a list. When there are multiple `CPoint` objects in a list, `pickle` is clever enough to save the Class-header only once.

I choose a slightly different test-setup - the coordinates are chosen randomly from the range `[-2e9,2e9]`, which basically covers the whole int32-range (it is nice to know, that `pickle` is clever enough to reduce the number of needed bytes for small values, but how large is the gain depends on the distribution of the points):

```
N=10000
x_lst=[random.randint(-2*10**9, 2*10**9) for _ in range(N)]
y_lst=[random.randint(-2*10**9, 2*10**9) for _ in range(N)]
```

and compare lists of`Point`s, `CPoint`s and `int32`-structured numpy arrays:

```
lst_p  = [ Point(x,y)  for x,y in zip(x_lst, y_lst)]
lst_cp = [ CPoint(x,y) for x,y in zip(x_lst, y_lst)]
lst_np = np.array(list(zip(x_lst, y_lst)), dtype=[('x',np.int32),('y',np.int32)])
```

That yields the following results:

```
 print("Point", len(pickle.dumps(lst_p,protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL))/N)   
 print("CPoint", len(pickle.dumps(lst_cp,protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL))/N)    
 print("nparray", len(pickle.dumps(lst_np,protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL))/N)

 Point 16.0071
 CPoint 25.0145 
 nparray 8.0213
```

That means nparray needs only 8 bytes per entry (differently as in @DavidW's answers I look at size of the whole object and not per integer-value), which is as good as it gets. This is due to the fact, that I use `np.int32` and not `int` (which are usually 64 bites) for the coordinates.

One important point: numpy-arrays are still better than list of `Point`s even if they had only small coordinates - in this case the size would be about 12 bytes, as the @DavidW's experiments have shown.

But one might like CPoint-objects more than the numpy-structs. So which other options do we have?

An easy possibility would be not to use the automatically created pickling-functionality, but do it by hand:

```
%%cython
cdef class CPoint:
    ...

    def __getstate__(self):
        return (self.x, self.y)

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.x, self.y=state
```

And now:

```
 >>> pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(CPoint(1,3)))
 Point(x=1, y=3)
 >>> print("CPoint", len(pickle.dumps(lst_cp,protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL))/N)  
 CPoint 18.011
```

Still 2 bytes worse than `Point` but also 7 bytes better than the original version. A plus is also that we would profit from the smaller size for smaller integers - but would still stay 2 bytes shy of the `Point`-version.

Another approach would be to define a dedicated list-of-CPoints-class/wraper:

%%cython
import array
cdef class CPointListWrapper:
    cdef list lst
    def **init**(self, lst):
        self.lst=lst

```
def release_list(self):
    result=self.lst
    self.lst=[]
    return result

def __getstate__(self):    
    output=array.array('i',[0]*(2*len(self.lst)))
    for index,obj in enumerate(self.lst):
        output[index*2]  =obj.x
        output[index*2+1]=obj.y
    return output

def __setstate__(self, in_array):
    self.lst=[]
    n=len(in_array)//2
    for i in range(n):
        self.lst.append(CPoint(in_array[2*i], in_array[2*i+1]))
```

It is obviously quick and dirty and a lot could be improved performance-wise, but I hope you get the gist! And now:

```
 >>> print("CPointListWrapper", len(pickle.dumps(CPointListWrapper(lst_cp),protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL))/N)
 CPoint 8.0149
```

as good as numpy but sticks to CPoint-objects! It is also working correctly:

```
>>> pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(CPointListWrapper([CPoint(1,2), CPoint(3,4)]))).release_list()
[Point(x=1, y=2), Point(x=3, y=4)]
```